# Angular Error: [$injector:modulerr] global controllers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm doing a course of Angularjs, and I have to do an exercise, but for me is imposible to run this:

app.js:

```
function OcultarController($scope) {
  $scope.oculto = true;

  $scope.cambioColor = function() {
    $scope.oculto = !$scope.oculto;
  };
}

angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('myModule').config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="OcultarController">
      <p style="background-color:red;" ng-show="oculto">ROJO</p>
      <p style="background-color:green;" ng-hide="oculto">VERDE</p>
      <button ng-click="cambioColor()">Cambiar color</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I try to make it work but I can't, I'm newbie in Angularjs, and I don't know if I'm do it well, The exercise just tell me to copy-past the code, but what i see isn't so easy.

The console tell me this(I'm using firefox):

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/nomod?p0=myModule angular.min.js:6:417
"Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15    /ng/areq?p0=OcultarController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
R/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:6:417
Rb@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:19:1
sb@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:20:78
Fe/this.$get</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:75:396
B/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:57:100
r@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:7:406
B@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:56:471
g@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:51:335
g@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:51:352
g@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:51:352
D/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:50:444
uc/d/</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15   /angular.min.js:18:4
Pe/this.$get</n.prototype.$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:126:11
Pe/this.$get</n.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:126:236
uc/d/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:17:477
e@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:36:313
uc/d@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:17:1
uc@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:18:179
Jd@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:17:1
@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:250:429
a@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:164:283
lf/c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:32:384
"
```

Comment: `<script src="app.js></script>` => You are missing a " here

Comment: Changing that html load, but the error persist

Comment: use not minified angular to see readable error. [_Module 'myModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument._](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=myModule)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are creating two modules here (which is not necessarily a problem, but in your case I guess you don't need that):

```
angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('myModule').
```

Change it to:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);

app.controller('OcultarController', OcultarController);
```

Comment: Perfect!!!! That works for me, thanks! Could you explain it to me? Because I want to use global functions as controller, but what i see here, I'm assing that as proper function.

Comment: @JoseteManu you just not create module with name _myModule_ but try use it

Comment: There is not much to explain here. The `app` variable will hold the reference of your angular module named "app" (this can be whatever you'd like) and you set the config on that. Moreover, you tell angular that you have a controller in your app module named "OcultarController".

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell your "app" that it should load your module "myModule".

Change

```
angular.module('app', []);
```

to

```
angular.module('app', ['myModule']);
```

and move it to the end of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/Vx5FuIemuj636r3ixzWt?p=preview

```
angular.module('app', []).controller("OcultarController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.oculto = true;

  $scope.cambioColor = function() {
    $scope.oculto = !$scope.oculto;
  };
}]).config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);
```